# In reality, is the spot price of a publicly-traded stock determined by a central algorithm as a best guess?

Tags: stocks

Every resource I've read about how a publicly-traded stock's spot price is determined says that supply and demand is a major *component* but not the whole pie. I've read about naked shorts (which are now illegal among stocks but apparently still exist in practice in other dubious manifestations) and how counterfeit shares can affect spot price. I've read about short ladder attacks that can apparently "trick algorithms" into driving a spot price down. And I've read other things as well.

That said, when someone sees a publicly-traded stock's spot price as $1.25, for example, is that number identical across all other brokers in real time? Does that mean then that a central algorithm is computing the spot price as a best guess of what it thinks the market value actually is? And if so, what sorts of things are also considered in this algorithm and how transparent is it? Because nothing I've read from authoritative sources says that it's entirely supply and demand.

Comment: Your understanding of "price" is utterly, utterly, utterly, utterly, utterly confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naked shorting is still supply and demand.  It's just illegal supply.

For exchange traded stocks in the U.S.:

> The [National Best Bid and Offer](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nbbo.asp) (NBBO) is a Securities Exchange Commission (SEC) regulation requiring brokers to trade at the best available (lowest) ask price and the best available (highest) bid price when buying and selling securities for customers.

> The [NBBO is calculated](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nbbo.asp#:%7E:text=The%20NBBO%20is%20calculated%20and%20disseminated%20by%20Security,There%20are%20two%20SIPs%20responsible%20for%20this%20task.) and disseminated by Security Information Processors (SIP) as part of the National Market System Plan (NMSP), which is used to process security prices.

That means that current orders on the order book  determine what the current price and it is totally based on supply and demand.  The only reason that this number will deviate from broker to broker (I have seen it) is that the speed of one broker's quote dissemination is fractionally slower than another.

Answer (score 2):

> is that number identical across all other brokers in real time?

It should be very close, or only deviate for a very short time. otherwise there's be an arbitrage opportunity (buy a stock from one broker and sell it through another) that would bring the prices in line. High-frequency traders actually exist to take advantage of short-lived differences across brokers in this manner.

> Does that mean then that a central algorithm is computing the spot price as a best guess of what it thinks the market value actually is?

Not at all - it's still driven by supply and demand, materialized through orders placed in the central exchange (e.g. NYSE)

Comment: So in practice, every broker calculates their own spot prices all using the same central data source from the exchange itself? Why do these articles say that supply and demand is a component of the calculation and not the entire equation itself?

Comment: Brokers don't "calculate their own spot prices" for exchange-traded instruments, only for non-exchange traded things like corporate bonds. For equities they show you what the "current" bid and ask are at the exchange. That's what you have to pay (or get if you're selling). I can't explain what these articles mean, but it's possible that they're not considering speculation or market manipulation part of "supply and demand". Or maybe they're just avoiding absolute terms. You'd have to link to an actual article for us to understand the context.

Comment: If the brokers don't calculate spot prices but merely display prices straight from the exchange then how could there be a disparity of spot prices between brokers?

Comment: By "straight from the exchange" I mean that they are displaying the actual bid/ask prices from the exchange (not computed or manipulated). There is still a very, very short time delay for the broker to actually get the date, run through whatever computing systems they have, etc. Some brokers are faster than others, resulting in short-lived discrepancies (which is part of what HFT algorithms exploit).